# Reportlab LinePlot - how do I add a lineLegend...or label my lines?

Tags: legend, reportlab, line-plot

I have a lineplot with 2 lines on it...they're two separate channels from the same data set. Would love to just label each one - the "labels" options are all about giving a number for each point on your plot, and that is simply not helpful.

Would love to know how to do any (really, all, but I just need to do one to be happy) of these:

- plot each against its own y axis and be able to sensibly label that axis with units (and color the numbers to correspond to the data it correlates to)
- put a legend on it. I can't figure out how to use lineLegend
- just put any kind of (singular) label in the vicinity of the lines.

Comment: I'm finding this post very helpful: [python - 2 Axes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826761/2-axes-reportlab-graph)